# Irrationality of numbers in ZFC

Tags: logic, irrational-numbers

Define the number $\alpha$ as $\alpha=\sum _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{f(n)}{10^{n!}}$, where $f(n)=1$ if there's a proof of 0=1 in ZFC of length n, and $f(n)=0$ otherwise.

Then, the statement "$\alpha$ is a rational number" (or an algebraic number for that matter) is independent of the axioms of ZFC.

However, that example is very contrived.

Could it be possible that the statement "$\alpha$ is rational" is independent of ZFC, where $\alpha$ is a more familiar number such as $\alpha=e+\pi$?

Answer (score 4):

In principle, sure! In practice, we have no reason to believe that such a statement is independent of ZFC.

Note that the sentence "$e+\pi$ is rational" (say) is a relatively simple one - in the hierarchy of complexity of sentences (see e.g. here), it is at the $\Pi^0_2$ level. Such statements cannot be proved independent via *forcing* (which is currently the most prolific way of demonstrating independence from ZFC), or via *inner models* (which is the second most); so the only obvious way to show that it is independent of ZFC would be to show that it is related to the *consistency* of ZFC. The problem is that such arguments generally go through *fast-growing functions*, and there isn't obviously a fast-growing function associated to the (ir)rationality of $e+\pi$.

Now this doesn't mean that "$e+\pi$ is rational" is decidable in ZFC, of course! For one thing, there are extremely clever arguments for independence which are more subtle than what I've outlined above, and which I know nothing about; Harvey Friedman has done a lot of work in this area. Conceivably such a technique could apply here. And of course even if no *currently known* technique suffices, that doesn't mean we won't find one later. And - worst of all! - it might be the case that *we can't prove* that "$e+\pi$ is rational" is independent of ZFC, even if it is!

So all the evidence we have in any direction is entirely heuristic. Personally, I believe "$e+\pi$ is rational" *is* decidable (disprovable, specifically) from ZFC; but I have to admit that I have no real evidence for this belief.

Comment: Is there a scenario where you can prove that you *can't* prove the independence of some statement?

Comment: @Ohad Yes, artificial examples can be constructed (although to the best of my knowledge no *natural* example is currently known). However, here we have to be very careful: we need to specify what theory is proving (or not proving) what. For example, the proof that "ZFC does not prove Con(ZFC)" takes place in a *stronger* theory than ZFC (ZFC+Con(ZFC) suffices); this is because, if ZFC proved "ZFC does not prove Con(ZFC)," then ZFC would prove Con(ZFC), because if ZFC is inconsistent then it proves everything (and it knows this). (cont'd)

Comment: Another good example is something like the Goldbach conjecture, any counterexample to which can be verified by (much less than) ZFC: if Goldbach is *not disprovable* in ZFC, then it is true! And ZFC (much less even) proves this. In particular, if T is a reasonable theory that proves "Goldbach is undecidable in ZFC," then T proves Goldbach; so in a sense, Goldbach is provably not provably unprovable. My point is just that we need to be very careful to specify what theories we're looking at when we talk about (un)provability.